# subtraction not happens given time and current time when convert to date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

//i am checking if given time is lapsed or not compare to current machine time.
                //i am not getting alert even time start time and endtime is lapsed.

```
 var currDate  = new Date();
    var startDate = setTime("09:30:00");
    var endDate   = setTime("10:15:00");
```

// given an input string of format "hh:mm:ss", returns a date object with 
// the same day as today, but the given time.

```
function setTime(timeStr) {
    var dateObj = new Date();          // assuming date is today
    var timeArr = timeStr.split(':');  // to access hour/minute/second
    var hour    = timeArr[0]; 
    var minute  = timeArr[1];
    var second  = timeArr[2];

    dateObj.setHours(hour);
    dateObj.setMinutes(minute);
    dateObj.setSeconds(second);
    return dateObj;
}
```

// now we can subtract them (subtracting two Date objects gives you their 
// difference in milliseconds)

```
if (currDate - startDate < 0 || currDate - endDate < 0) {
    alert("Unfortunately, you can't schedule a meeting in the past. 
             We apologize for the inconvenience.");
}
```

Comment: If the time is elapsed, the difference should be > 0 (currDate > startDate).

Comment: currDate > startDate and what about end date

Comment: In general, a date which is _later_ has _more_ milliseconds.

Comment: so how i use my logic or it is wrong

Comment: `if startDate < currDate || endDate < currDate` -- one of the dates is in the past

Comment: it genearte alerts always even i give time "19:15:00"  "19:30:00" which is greater than current time 04:00:00PM

Answer (score 0):

In order to check given time is lapsed or not compare to current machine time change the condition as mentioned below.

```
if (currDate > startDate && currDate  < endDate) 
{
    alert("Unfortunately, you can't schedule a meeting in the past. We apologize for the inconvenience.");
}
```

It will show the alert if the current time falls in between start time and end time.

Let me know if it worked.